# Neo4j Chaining Queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a CypherQL equivalent of the below SQL statement?

```
SELECT name from table t
WHERE t.field IN 
(SELECT * from othertable ot)
```

Was thinking it may be something like this?

```
MATCH (e)--(m)
MATCH (a) where a.field in e.otherfield return a
```

(e) returns a list of strings and i want to only execute the second query based on those strings.

Comment: When you create the node in graphDb, you can consider beforehand that rather than storing the data as a list, you will create an edge between table t and othertable ot. Concept of connected data is not the same with relational db (sql). If I will load the data into neo4j as such, my cypher query is simply Match (e:Node1) -- (Node2) Return e.name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you meet your expectations, and I wouldn't recommend it honestly, do you mean below?

```
MATCH(othertable)
WITH REDUCE(values = [], key IN KEYS(othertable) | values + othertable[key]) AS values
MATCH(t) WHERE t.field IN values
RETURN t.name
```